# Record Screen using ffmpeg doesn't work in tomcat server(Could not find codec parameters for stream 0)

Tags: java, ffmpeg, tomcat8

I have the following problem,when I executed the below FFMPEG terminal command in command it prompt successfully.

```
    C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -i desktop -c:v libx264 -analyzeduration 15M -probesize 15M -pix_fmt yuv420p -loglevel 99 C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\video.mp4
```

but I have a problem while running a command from a java web application.I used `runtime.exec()`. It's working fine at Netbeans. But not working at all after deploying on tomcat server.
 
 
Here is my code :

```
String command = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\"
            + "ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -i desktop -c:v libx264 -analyzeduration 15M -probesize 15M -pix_fmt yuv420p -loglevel 99 C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\video.mp4";

    System.out.println("command = " + command);
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        final InputStreamReader isr
                = new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream());
        Thread th = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        };
        th.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error 1 : " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error 2 : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

And here is log for error

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'gdigrab'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'desktop'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option '-analyzeduration' ... matched as AVOption 'analyzeduration' 
with argument '15M'.
Reading option '-probesize' ... matched as AVOption 'probesize' with argument '15M'.
Reading option '-pix_fmt' ... matched as option 'pix_fmt' (set pixel format) with argument 'yuv420p'.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument '99'.
Reading option 'C:\ffmpeg\bin\video.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument 99.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url desktop.
Applying option f (force format) with argument gdigrab.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: desktop.
[gdigrab @ 0000007c2a72ad00] Capturing whole desktop as 1024x768x32 at (0,0)
[gdigrab @ 0000007c2a72ad00] Failed to capture image (error 5)
[gdigrab @ 0000007c2a72ad00] stream 0: start_time: -9223372036854.775 duration: -9223372036854.775
[gdigrab @ 0000007c2a72ad00] format: start_time: -9223372036854.775 duration: -9223372036854.775 bitrate=754233 kb/s
[gdigrab @ 0000007c2a72ad00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: bmp, 1 reference frame, none, 754233 kb/s): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, gdigrab, from 'desktop':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: 754233 kb/s
Stream #0:0, 0, 1/1000000: Video: bmp, 1 reference frame, none, 754233 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url C:\ffmpeg\bin\video.mp4.
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument libx264.
Applying option pix_fmt (set pixel format) with argument yuv420p.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: C:\ffmpeg\bin\video.mp4.
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\ffmpeg\bin\video.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Can anyone help me to get out of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably a permissions or UAC issue.

Comment: I try to change UAC to Never notify but didn't solve my problem, can you tell me how to handle permission ?  @llogan

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know. I'm not a Windows user.